# How can I use a RelativeLayout or LinearLayout inside in ConstraintLayout

Tags: android-constraintlayout

[image]I am unable to add the inner layout (Relative layout or liner layout) inside the constraint layout. What do I have to do if I do

Comment: No one will be able to help you without you adding code to the question. Generally, it is bad practice to use nesting inside constraintLayout.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,
Actually I want to develop recycler view with the help of constraint layout but I don't know how can I achieve this
Generally, when we use relative layout and liner layout this is easier. But I want to make this layout by constraint layout.